# Does Spring WebFlux automatically close connections when using .retrieve() or .exchange()?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

We recently switched from a JAX RS-based WebClient to Spring's reactive WebFlux client. As we had problems with the old client retaining connections in some cases, we were wondering how the WebFlux client treats those. Unfortunately, [Spring's documentation for WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.19.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) doesn't provide details on this, only in the context of WebSockets. So: Does calling `.retrieve()` or `.exchange()` automatically close connections? Or do we need to take care of that on our own?

Comment: That link of yours does seem to state quite a few about releasing resources though, e.g. section 2.1: _"When `onStatus` is used, if the response is expected to have content, then the `onStatus` callback should consume it. If not, the content will be automatically drained to ensure resources are released."_; and section 2.2: _"When using `exchange()` you must always use any of the body or toEntity methods of `ClientResponse` to ensure resources are released and to avoid potential issues with HTTP connection pooling. [...]"_. Or are you looking for other more in-depth details than those?

Comment: I was hoping for more insight into combinations with `.retrieve()`, such as `retrieve().bodyToMono()`.